# rem media query and mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to change the design of the website I'm building to give a better user experience for mobile users. I've read about media queries and even though I'm not sure it's the way to go there is something I don't understand : 
My computer screen is 1920x1080. I just checked the iphone 6 screen is the same.
So 1920 / 16 = 120. So my pc screen is 120rem wide.

If I have a media query that applies only under 119 rem will it apply to the iphone 6 (or any phone with that screen spec) or not ?

I'm asking because I'm wondering what will the user see if I use rem based media queries. Will the user see the website zoomed out or the media query based design?

Comment: If you have an iPhone 6, create a simple page with that media query (changing the font color), and open it with from computer and with the iPhone.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro what makes you think I have an iphone 6 ? This was an example to illustrate a misunderstanding I have. I don't own a phone at the moment.